# Solr search ignoring first word

Tags: php, solr, cpu-word, phrase

I've looked around SO and elsewhere online but haven't found anything specific to my problem. I was wondering anyone else experienced it? And how did they resolve?

I am trying to do a wildcard search for a multi worded field, which works fine while I type the first word, but as soon as I start typing the second word the first word gets ignored.

Each document of my index represents one person and has the indexed field 'name'.

```
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
```

**What should happen:**

When I type: 'Bruce Rob' it should return the document 'Bruce Robertson'.

**What is happening:**

When I type 'Bru' it *does* return 'Bruce Robertson'. But as soon as I start the second word e.g. 'Bruce Rob' it will begin to return results that start with 'Rob' - totally ignoring the word that came before.

I'm using the PHP client library. The query it generates looks like so:

```
fq=type%3Aperson&sort=id+desc&wt=json&json.nl=map&q=name%3Abruce+rob%2A&start=0&rows=3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: PHP Code**

```
$options = array('fq' => "type:person",'sort' => 'id desc');
$results = $this->solr->search('name:' . $val . '*', 0, 3, $options);
```

Comment: How is your string fieldType defined in your `schema.xml`?

Comment: hi, it's defined like so: 
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>

Comment: I think there's something missing in the question. How could you get results if you search for 'Rob' with that field type? Rob isn't a term in your index, you're not making a wildcard query, and you're not even using NGrams. Could you check if your questions contains all the information?

Comment: My question says: "I am trying to do a wildcard search", also if you look at my query: "q=name%3Abruce+rob%2A"

Comment: Clear, maybe you should add the * to your queries within the text. What query parser are you using?

Comment: I've added my PHP code above so it's easier to see how the query is being constructed. Where can I check my query parser? I don't remember specifying one - so maybe it's the default (not sure which that is though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is searching for bruce in the name field `name:bruce` but since rob isn't qualified with a field name it will search for `rob*` against the default field `defaultSearchField` defined in your schema.

Comment: I see. The defaultSearchField happens to be 'name' also. So, how can I make sure that both words are treated as one entity?

Comment: Try searching `q=name:"bruce rob*"`

Comment: That's what I am doing. $var in my post is equal to "bruce rob", then I append the *.

Comment: You sure? It doesn't look like it in your example: `&q=name%3Abruce+rob%2A&`

Comment: You're right, sorry. Now I try passing: 'name:"bruce rob*"' into the search method of the client library it strips these quotation marks by the time the query is sent to solr.

Comment: Wildcards inside phrase queries are not yet supported. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1604

Comment: I've implemented ComplexPhraseQueryParser though the first word still seems not to be respected. Here is my query: fq=type:person&sort=date+desc&defType=complexphrase&wt=json&json.nl=map&q=name:bruce+rob*&start=0&rows=3. But the results are listing items such as 'Robert Johnson' rather than 'Bruce Robertson'

Comment: What is the `defaultOperator` value in your schema.xml? Maybe it's set to `OR` you could also try something like `q=name:bruce AND name:rob*`

Comment: Got the answer in the comments. Thanks guys. I needed to use ComplexPhraseQueryParser and construct the query like so: q=name:bruce AND rob*. Excellent!